# Qt Creator breakpoint won't stop on el capitan

Tags: qt, qt-creator, lldb, osx-elcapitan

Last time I used Qt Creator, it was still using gdb (not lldb) and it's working just fine before upgrading to El Capitan.

Has anybody managed to debug using Qt Creator 3.4.2 and Qt 5.5.0 on El Capitan?
Can someone please give me any pointers of how to set it up correctly since mine does not even stop at breakpoint?

Comment: Which gdb were you using? Xcode only ships lldb for quite a while now (and at least on Yosemite, creator works fine with it, for me). What's the debugger setting in your kit?

Comment: Compiler Clang (x86 64bit in /usr/bin), Debugger: System LLDB at /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/lldb, and Qt version: Qt 5.5.0 clang 64 bit. I have just installed using offline installer and didn't change any of it. Do you have any modification into your debugger setting in your kit Frank?

Comment: No, that's what i use, too

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and clicking on Enable QML in the Debugger Settings (from Projects > Execution parameters) seems to make the breaking points work again.

I ignore why and it complains about not being able to connect to the QML debug process *after* the end of the debugging session, but at least the breaking points work now.
I also have lldb and not gdb.

Answer (score 0):

QT5.6.2 with macOS 10.11.6, after a totally reinstall I finally solved it, my solution:

- in terminal,`brew uninstal qt`(maybe this is the problem)
- run MaintenanceTool.app,see [Uninstall and Reinstall QtSDK on Mac system](https://wiki.qt.io/Howto_do_a_clean_uninstall_and_reinstall_of_qt_sdk)
- reboot
- reinstall Qt

Answer (score 0):

This is just a blind guess, i had the same problem. I solved it with the following configuration the .pro:

```
CONFIG -= app_bundle
```

Looks like debugging doesn't work inside a bundle.